# Mysql : syntax error after update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

please advice whats the error in this statement, this statement was working fine before the last update for mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      username VARCHAR(50),
                      password VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
                      full_name VARCHAR(50),
                      is_author BOOLEAN DEFAULT  ,
                      UNIQUE INDEX (username));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please include waht is the exactt error your getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `DEFAULT` or set to value:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      username VARCHAR(50),
                      `password` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
                      full_name VARCHAR(50),
                      is_author BOOLEAN,  -- here or DEFAULT true/false
                      UNIQUE INDEX (username));
```

Also qoute `password` because it is keyword.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b2a9/1/0)**</kbd>